# Laravel 8: Target class [ProductController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel-8 to develop my project, and I have a resource controller named `ProductController` which is placed at `Admin` directory inside `Controllers`, just like this image is showing:

[image: capture]

Then at my route file, I coded this:

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('permissions', 'PermissionController');
```

But when I want to go to `products` route, I get this message:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> **[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController] does not exist.**

Now you may say in Laravel-8, I have to use `Route::get('/', ProductController::class);`, but as you can see above, I have also determined a `permissions` route to `PermissionController` by the old method and it is working completely fine!

The namespace of Admin is also specified at `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
Route::middleware(['web' , 'auth' , 'auth.admin'])
                ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
                ->prefix('admin')
                ->group(base_path('routes/web/admin.php'));
```

Note that I also tried `Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);` , but still get the same error.

I guess the issue is coming from another part!

So if you have any idea about this, please let me know, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1:**

`ProductController` goes like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Product;
```

Comment: I'm confused. What's actually working and what's not working? Which controller is found and which one is not?

Comment: @apokryfos `ProductController` is not found. I tried the both old and new ways to call this Controller, but still can not be found.

Comment: Please share the first lines of your ProductController.php file as well.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I did, see `UPDATE #1` plz

Comment: your namespace on that fie is wrong ... it is missing the Admin part of the namespace, as the answer below states

Answer (score 4):

You just need go to
app/Http/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

**uncomment**:
*protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe82c.png)

Answer (score 3):

Inside your ProductController, you need to have namespace like this

> namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried that but still receive: `Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController] does not exist.`

Comment: The `ProductController` should have this namespace declared as it is in the `Admin` folder  ... PSR4 autoloading

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your namespace:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController;
```

Then on your route:

```
Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this answer would help anyone or not but, I think you haven't imported the `ProductController` into your `api.php`

There are two widely used ways to import in laravel:

**1st way-**
As @Talita suggested, import the file with the `use` syntax and then call out the class in `Route::apiResource`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController;

Route::apiResource('products', ProductController::class);
```

**2nd way-**
You can call the class's location within the `Route::apiResource` just as follows-

```
Route::apiResource('/products', '\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductController');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just to put the path instead the name of the Controller
You can change in your web.php:

```
Route::resource('products','ProductController');
```

to:

```
Route::resource('products','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController');
```

Answer (score -1):

you should remove line use namespace... controller in route page.